# Some issues with installing angular2 on local machine

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm

I downloaded the *.msi package of nodejs from nodejs dot org and installed it. I checked if it's installed properly by checking the version of it via cmd(I'm using win8.1 64bit) - `node -v` it responded with `v6.10.0`, then I tried the following command to install angular cli - `npm install -g angular-cli` and it run with some notices(WARNs), about skipping optional dependency of  fsevents@1.0.0, unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.1, `@angular/core@2.4.10` requires a peer of rxjs@^5.0.1...

So after that, I ran this command: `npm install -g rxjs@5.0.1` and It finished with the following:

```
`-- rxjs@5.0.1
  `-- symbol-observable@1.0.4.
```

Then I tired to create a new angular-2 project via following command: `ng new myproject`. And after that, I only have 3 directories inside myproject: e2e, node_modules, src.

Is this is how it should be, because I think there should be much more directories( `public`, for example). If it's not right, what should I do, and how should I do it properly, please?

Comment: Yes, that's how it should be. Why do you think there should be a public directory?

Comment: because everywhere it says so... as far as I got it, it's missing because while installing angular-cli some of node dependencies were missing

Comment: Where is "everywhere"? Can you point me any place in the angular cli documentation where it says there should be a public directory? Because anywhere else is completely irrelevant. It's not missing. What you get is absolutely normal and expected.

Comment: Alright, thanks Nizet